# Flutter (mailer package): mailing from within the app. not receiving mail

Tags: email, flutter

I am working on an app in flutter, and I would like to have a "give feedback option". this form consists of 1 text field where the message is typed, and 1 button to submit and sent the feedback.

I am currently using the mailer(1) dart package to do this for me, but so far I have not been able to send and receive a mail in my inbox.

I have used flutter_mailer and mailer, both without any success. I followed instructions and tried to do the same as the example, but I can not get it working.

the show code is the method to handle the email.

```
void sendEmail(String message) async {
  _isLoading = true;
  notifyListeners();

  print(message);
  String username = 'matthijs******@gmail.com';
  String password = '******';

  final SmtpServer server = gmail(username, password);
  final feedbackMessage = new Message()
  ..from = new Address(username, _authUser.email)
  ..recipients.add('m.dethmers2@hotmail.nl')
  ..ccRecipients.addAll([_authUser.email])
  ..subject = 'Feedback from ${_authUser.id} ${new DateTime.now()}'
  ..text = message
  ..html = "<h1>Test</h1>\n<p>message</p>";

final sendReports = await send(feedbackMessage, server, timeout: 
Duration(seconds: 15));

_isLoading = false;
notifyListeners();
print('email send');
```

}

i would like to see an email appear in my inbox with the written message of the user in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, it seems like you should create an app password of the desired account.

you can ollow this link https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en to create an app password. use this password in conjunction with the email in the mailer implementation and everything should work!